# Bean can not be created if the broker is down

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I use Spring AMQP + RabbitMQ. Usually, Spring handles the situation if rabbitmq-server is turned off. App throws exceptions but still tries to reconnect. However, if i put amqp bean inside another bean as it's property application fails on startup. I get this error

```
31 мая 2018 17:31:24.902 [communication-server-0.15.15][o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh] WARN  Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'driverManager' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:15672/api/queues/": Connect to localhost:15672 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: В соединении отказано (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:15672 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: В соединении отказано (Connection refused)
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'driverManager' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:15672/api/queues/": Connect to localhost:15672 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: В соединении отказано (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:15672 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: В соединении отказано (Connection refused)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
  at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
  at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:105)
  at ru.ru.Server.run(CommunicationServer.java:36)
  at ru.rubServer.main(CommunicationServer.java:42)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:15672/api/queues/": Connect to localhost:15672 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: В соединении отказано (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:15672 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: В соединении отказано (Connection refused)
  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:666)
  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:628)
  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:303)
  at com.rabbitmq.http.client.Client.getQueues(Client.java:409)
  at ru.rub.DriverManager.removeUnusedQueues(DriverManager.java:340)
  at ru.rub.DriverManager.initialize(DriverManager.java:158)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
  ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:15672 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: В соединении отказано (Connection refused)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:319)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
  at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:89)
  at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
  at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:652)
  ... 25 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: В соединении отказано (Connection refused)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
  at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:72)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:125)
  ... 38 more
```

Any ideas on how to handle that? I don't want my app to crush if rabbitmq-server is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show the full stack trace.

However, it looks like you might be trying to connect to the broker before the application context is fully ready and refreshed. You must not connect to the broker in `@PostConstruct` methods, `afterPropertiesSet()` methods etc.

You should never perform operations with external systems on the thread that's builing the application context while the application context is being built.

Comment: i am not using @PostConstruct. and what type of operations with external systems you are talking about?

Comment: According the stack trace there is a problem with an HTTP connection, not RabbitMQ

Comment: See `invokeInitMethods` - `DriverManager.initialize()` is calling `removeUnusedQueues` which is trying to call RabbitMQ over HTTP. It's too early to do that; you must wait until the application context is completely refreshed. `init-method`s are just like `@PostConstruct`; that's why I said "etc". You also must not interact with external systems in methods like setters, constructors etc.

Comment: @GaryRussell but what do i do then if my `driverManager` should contain rabbit beans?

Comment: There is no problem having Spring beans there; you just can't do stuff like that in initialization methods (or put them in a try catch and schedule to retry later). One solution would be to move that initialization logic to a `ConnectionListener` which you add to the `CachingConnectionFactory`. Your listener will be called when a new connection is successfully established.

Comment: what are the alternatives here other than doing `init()` logic in connection listener because i dont want an extra thread in my app?

Comment: What do you mean by "extra thread" there is no extra thread, the listener is invoked on whatever thread opens the connection.

Comment: before adding the connection listener, `init()` logic was running in main thread, now it's running in `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer`. the problem now is that i am starting listener container and it waits for 60 seconds because the count of `CountDownLatch` is `1` and it was `0` before

Comment: Well, you are in a catch-22; you want the app to start if the broker's not there but you want to initialize the connection on the main thread if it is. One option is to set autoStartup to false on the container; after the context is initialized try to create a connection on the main thread (in a loop until it succeeds) and then `start()` the container.

Comment: the app shouldn't completely start. it should wait for rabbitconnection

Comment: In that case, just put a `try/catch` with `Thread.sleep()` in a loop your `DriverManager.initialize()` method.